# A book or short story about planet colonizing

Tags: story-identification, planets

I remember reading it at school but do not remember if it was in a collection of short stories or a book.
It was the 80's so it would be that time or before the 80's.
What I remember is a new planet the ship I think crashed or had a malfunction and some how some dna got mixed up.
I remember the main character watching what was either a seal hybrid or a dolphin hybrid swimming.It was mixed up with something weird that today we know would not happen.
Its been over 20 years and that's about all I can remember.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a long shot, but... David Brin's "[Startide Rising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising)"?  The fit:

- Written 1983
- Ship hiding on a planet for repairs.
- Dolphin crew (with some humans).  Not "mixed up DNA" but "uplifted".
- Actually, I note the WP article mentions "Parts of Startide Rising were published as "The Tides of Kithrup" in the May 1981 issue of Analog." so maybe that's what you read.

Comment: There was no dolphin crew and they where colonizing the planet. Does sound like and interesting read though.
I am thinking the main character might have been a young lady.

Comment: @Peggy: Any chance it was [The Uplift War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Uplift_War), another book in the same series?